# Show my iphone application in Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i want make possible to post on facebook page a description of my app.
I've tried ShareKit, but after registering an app on facebook and insert the key and the secret in config file of SHK, i don't have what i want.
How can i give to user the chance to advertise my app on facebook?

Comment: "i don't have what i want" I like the specific critiques that help us to figure out what it isn't doing that you need addressed in another library.

Comment: Sorry my english is very poor. The sense of my sentence is not negative, not a critic to that great library but i mean that i wanted another kind of result

Comment: OK, but my point is, we can't just guess at what ShareKit isn't able to do for you. What issue are you running into with ShareKit?

Answer (score 0):

Use [facebook graph api](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) ..you can postFeed from this api and also give itunes link of your app and description